# align the last flex items at the right bottom of next line

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to achieve where the last two items would be align at the bottom right side of the flex.
This is my cdoe structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="list-items">
  <div class="item">
   Item One
  </div>
    <div class="item">
   Item Two
  </div>
      <div class="item">
   Item three
  </div>
</div >
<div class="list-items">
  <div class="item">
   Item Four
  </div>
    <div class="item">
   Item Five
  </div>
      <div class="item">
   Item Six
  </div>
</div >
<div class="list-items">
  <div class="item">
   Item seven
  </div>
    <div class="item">
   Item Eight
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The last two items would be in the second div of flex, whereas in the first div will have multiple items that will be displayed as specific row.
Any ideas how can I achieve it.
Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rchwud7/94/) link, I am Playing around.
[image]

Comment: Just pass one empty div in last row and you can achieve desired result.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a table, so maybe you should use `<table>`?
If for some reason you do not want to do this, then judging by the screenshot, you need to apply `grid` + `grid-template-columns:subgrid`, because flexbox will not help here:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}

.list-items {
  grid-column: span 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.item {
   border:1px solid;
   padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-items">
    <div class="item">Item One</div>
    <div class="item">Item Two</div>
    <div class="item">Item three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <div class="item">Item Four</div>
    <div class="item">Item Five</div>
    <div class="item">Item Six</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <div></div>
    <div class="item">Item seven</div>
    <div class="item">Item Eight</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have 3 separate flex groups then the last `flex-items` div could have `justify-content: flex-end` on it.

```
<div class="list-items" style="justify-content: flex-end">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:grid` for the `.list-items` then use `grid-column-start: 2` to the `.item` that you want to start in 2nd column.

In this way, my HTML is almost similar to the ones you provided. I just added `item--gcs2` class to the 2nd to the last item (Item Seven div).

```css
.list-items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item--gcs2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-items">
    <div class="item">Item One</div>
    <div class="item">Item Two</div>
    <div class="item">Item Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <div class="item">Item Four</div>
    <div class="item">Item Five</div>
    <div class="item">Item Six</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-items">
    <div class="item item--gcs2">Item Seven</div>
    <div class="item">Item Eight</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

grid-column-start makes the item's start position to be 2nd grid column. You may refer to [MDN web docs grid-column-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start) for more info.